# SharePoint get value of rich text box control created programatically

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm writing a custom web part that need to use a couple of rich text box controls. I'm placing the controls onto the web part programatically. When the web part gets a save postback I'm able to capture the data from all the fields except the two rich text box ones. What's the trick to be able to get the value of a rich text box?

The code I"m using to place my form controls is:

```
    private void CreateInputControls()
    {
        inputPanel.Controls.Clear();

        SPList list = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Lists["MyList"];
        SPContentType cType = list.ContentTypes[0];

        Table table = new Table();
        table.CellPadding = 3;
        table.CellSpacing = 0;

        SPContext newContext = SPContext.GetContext(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, list.DefaultView.ID, list.ID, list.ParentWeb);

        foreach (SPField field in cType.Fields)
        {
            if (!field.Hidden && field.CanBeDisplayedInEditForm)
            {
                FieldLabel fieldLabel = new FieldLabel();
                fieldLabel.ControlMode = SPControlMode.New;
                fieldLabel.ListId = list.ID;
                fieldLabel.FieldName = field.InternalName;
                fieldLabel.ItemContext = newContext;
                fieldLabel.RenderContext = newContext;
                fieldLabel.Field.Required = fieldLabel.Field.Required;

                FormField formField = new FormField();
                formField.ControlMode = SPControlMode.New;
                formField.ListId = list.ID;
                formField.FieldName = field.InternalName;
                formField.ItemContext = newContext;
                formField.RenderContext = newContext;
                formField.ID = field.InternalName;
                formField.EnableViewState = true;

                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                table.Rows.Add(row);

                TableCell cellLabel = new TableCell();
                TableCell cellField = new TableCell();

                cellLabel.Controls.Add(fieldLabel);
                cellField.Controls.Add(formField);
                row.Cells.Add(cellLabel);
                row.Cells.Add(cellField);
            }
        }

        inputPanel.Controls.Add(table);
    }
```

The code I'm using to save a new item is:

```
    private void UpdateItem(string bannerImageURL, string thumbnailImageURL)
    {
        SPList list = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Lists["MyList"];
        SPContentType cType = list.ContentTypes[0];
        SPItem item = list.AddItem();

        foreach (SPField field in cType.Fields)
        {
            if (!field.Hidden && field.CanBeDisplayedInEditForm)
            {
                FormField formField = (FormField)inputPanel.FindControl(field.InternalName);

                if (formField != null)
                {
                     // Saves data for all fields EXCEPT for rich text box (sharepoint multiline columns).
                     item[field.Title] = formField.Value; 
                }
            }
        }

        item.Update();
    }
```

Comment: When the RTE control is found, is the `formField` variable null or not?

Comment: sipwiz, if you solved problem, please, tell how.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's an issue with the field name. Try to use the InternalName.

```
item[field.InternalName] = formField.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this and am using a workaround which I thought I'd post as this was quite frustrating.

The problem is that the RTE control is rendered empty and then populated from a hidden  control with JavaScript on the client.  However this hidden control is accessible server side thus:

```
switch (formField.Field.Type)
{
    case SPFieldType.Note:
        var rtf = (RichTextField)formField.Controls[0];
        item[field.Title] = rtf.HiddenInput.Value;
        break;
    default:
        item[field.Title] = formField.Value;
        break;
}
```

This may need extending for other field types but you get the idea...